# Image processing in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-ndk

I am trying to build an image processing application in android.
I want the application to function just like the barcode application where the scanning happens automatically; so the poster on the wall or the image will be scanned and a particular intent will be fired to do some task.

I dont know which approach to follow?? some guide me to use ndk while some say there are libraries out there.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: have you tried looking at barcode scanner sources? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout

Comment: i have used zxing library before but never tackled the code in it. Is this the most appropriate way ?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a try with the [Android port of OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android).

Since the brand new version 2.3.1 it is relatively easy to compile and deploy native (C++) and Java-based image processing programs to an Android device.
You need an Eclipse IDE, the JDK 6, Android SDK, and ADT plugin for Eclipse and you should follow the long [tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html) step by step. After that the examples should work and you can start to extend them to your needs.